# Fresh install of Raspbian - "Not enough space" with 16gb card

Tags: video

I just installed Raspbian and Pi_video_looper.  I wanted to put the looped videos on my card, so I adjusted the proper settings, but now when I try and transfer over the video file, i'm getting a message that there is not enough space.

It's a 16gb card..so im kind of confused how thats possible.  Did I do something wrong when formatting the card?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by proper settings? Is there a list of commands you used or a tutorial you followed? I would suggest going into Raspi-Config and checking that your file-system is set to use the full size of the SD card.

Comment: i didn't change any pi config files, only the video_looper settings, which shouldn't affect anything other than the fact that its looking for files in the pi directory rather than a usb drive .  Will check raspi-config. thanks

Comment: In `raspi-config` have you used `Expand Filesystem` yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install Raspbian, you often have to use the command `raspi-config`. This will bring up an interface, which will allow you to `Expand Filesystem`. The onscreen instructions are simple.